# How to have Netbeans projects export their dependencies like Eclipse does?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jar, ide

In Eclipse, if a project uses a particular JAR file, I can mark it to provide/export it.

So if another project has a reference to the former, then the particular JAR will be available too.

How can I do that in Netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans you always have to add JAR in the project properties, unless you use some deployment tools.

- Right click in your project
- Project Properties -> Libraries
- Add JAR