# Could not load the resource factory class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource

Tags: java, database-connection, tomcat6, jndi, connection-pooling

I want to do connection pooling using BoneCP. But i got a log of Could not load the resource factory class.
I got a this error log on tomcat startup

```
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource]
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:81)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:113)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:79)
    ... 17 more
```

I have added the resource to server.xml like this.

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

        <Resource type='javax.sql.DataSource'
              name='demodb'
           factory='com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource'
   driverClassName='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
           jdbcUrl='jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE'
          username='system'
          password='system'
        idleMaxAge='240'
     idleConnectionTestPeriod='60'
    partitionCount='3'
  acquireIncrement='5'
   maxConnectionsPerPartition='10'
   minConnectionsPerPartition='5'
          statementsCacheSize='50'
         releaseHelperThreads='5'
         />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

can anyone tell me what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that the class `com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource` was not found. Have you made sure that the class is loaded either by the server or your application?

It should be located in one of those [jars.](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource)

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Comment: I am using netbeans and i have loaded that(BoneCP 0.7.1) jar file in libraries but still i got this error on server startup.

Comment: OK, please make sure that the *BoneCP 0.7.1.jar* was loaded by the server either by copy it in the server library directory or by telling netbeans to export it with your project. I'm not sure how to do this properly in netbeans but I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096232/how-to-have-netbeans-projects-export-their-dependencies-like-eclipse-does) and hope this will set you on the right track. Cheers!

Comment: Ok let us suppose that i added that jar file in library manually.
After that i created my application war file. If i have to host that war file on a online server how can i add that jar file to online server library ?

Comment: AFAIK there should be an option in netbeans saying "mark this library as export dependency" but I'm not sure. You can chek if your library is deployed by looking into the *%TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps/<yourWebApp>/WEB-INF/lib*. If there is no file like *BoneCP 0.7.1.jar* you'll have to add it. If the file exists I'm at a loss for the moment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line:

```
     <pathelement location="/path/bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

into your classpath. Please correct the path if you want to use Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error can come due to mixed up jars. The connection pool uses a custom class loader and will not allow jars from different BoneCP/Datanucleus versions.